# How to create simple layer drawable in button

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, layerdrawable

I am trying to better understand how layer drawables work within a buttons drawable(s).

I am trying to draw 2 simple colored boxes, one without insets so that it fills the entire button drawable area.  And one with some inset.

```
ColorDrawable background1 = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
ColorDrawable background2 = new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN);
Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[] {
  background1,
  background2
};

LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(drawables);
ld.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ); // no inset on white box
ld.setLayerInset(1, 8, 8, 8, 8 ); // 8 inset on all side on green box

// set the left drawable on the button
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ld, null, null, null);
```

However that doesn't work at all.  The first problem is that the boxes are not filling any area.  Is that because a buttons drawables(s) don't have a predefined size?  If that is the case I tried to set the bound manually on the boxes, but didn't have much luck either.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @pskink thanks.  I don't fully understand how creating a BitmapDrawable fixes my problem, could you further explain?  IE how would I go about creating a bitmapdrawable that "fills" the buttons leftDrawable space?

Comment: No, I want to create my own "image" in a button drawables area.  IE a button has a leftDrawable, rightDrawable, etc.  I am trying to do it programmatically.  So doing this programmatically I am trying to start simple by drawing 2 colored boxes above.   Just to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Specific Design in Drawable and call in background button in xml

Comment: I would like to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem right now with `ColorDrawable` is that `getIntrinsicWidth()/getIntrinsicHeight()` that determine the bounds of the drawable are by default -1, thus it doesn't render on the screen. What would help in your case is to extend `ColorDrawable` and override the height and width from the constructor.

Here's a sample:

```
  class CustomDrawable(color: Int, val h: Int, val w: Int): ColorDrawable(color) {
    override fun getIntrinsicHeight(): Int {
      return h
    }

    override fun getIntrinsicWidth(): Int {
      return w
    }
  }
```

and then you can instantiate this instead of `ColorDrawable` like so

```
val background1 = CustomDrawable(Color.BLUE, dimensionInPx , dimensionInPx)
val background2 = CustomDrawable(Color.GREEN, dimensionInPx, dimensionInPx)
```

be sure to convert dp to px before passing these values

Hope this helps.